# Nextjs params query

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

Why is my total value not rendering on checkoutpage?
i tried passing out the amount={total} in the url
the total is passing down in the url but when i try to pass it down to checkout page it doesnt render on the page

```
export default function AddMoney({
  params,
}: {
  params: { accountId: string };
}) {
  
  
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col relative py-2 justify-between min-h-screen items-center gap-5 self-stretch">
      <HeaderBar leftButtonLabel={"Back"} leftButtonAction={"goBack"} />
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center self-stretch">
        <div className="px-8 mt-8">
          <PageTitles
            title="Add Money"
            subtitle={`
              Add money to spending profile(s) for in-person ordering or ordering ahead
              `}
          />
          <div className="flex p-0 flex-col items-center gap-8 self-stretch">
            <div className="flex p-0 flex-col justify-end items-start gap-4 self-stretch">
              {spendingProfiles?.map((profile, index) => {
                return (
                  <Card
                    key={profile.id}
                    className="flex p-3 flex-col items-center gap-4 self-stretch rounded-lg border bg-background"
                  >
                    <div className="flex p-0 flex-col items-start gap-1 self-stretch">
                      <p className=" text-xl font-semibold">{`${profile.studentName}`}</p>
                      <p className=" text-muted-foreground text-sm font-normal">
                        {`$${profile.balance} balance • $${profile.dailyLimit}/day limit`}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <ReloadTabs
                      index={index}
                      setPurchaseAmount={setPurchaseAmount}
                      purchaseAmount={purchaseAmount}
                      setCustomActive={setCustomActive}
                      customActive={customActive}
                      customAmount={customAmount}
                      setCustomAmount={setCustomAmount}
                      customLabel={"Enter a custom amount"}
                    />
                    <Separator />
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 self-stretch">
                      <div className="flex items-center gap-2 justify-start flex-row self-stretch">
                        <Switch
                          checked={autoRefill[index]}
                          onCheckedChange={() =>
                            handleChangeAutoRefill(autoRefill, index)
                          }
                        />
                        <h4 className=" text-sm font-medium">
                          {"Auto-refill when balance is low."}
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      {autoRefill[index] && (
                        <ReloadTabs
                          index={index}
                          setPurchaseAmount={setRefillAmount}
                          purchaseAmount={refillAmount}
                          setCustomActive={setCustomRefillActive}
                          customActive={customRefillActive}
                          customAmount={customRefillAmount}
                          setCustomAmount={setCustomRefillAmount}
                          customLabel="Choose a refill amount"
                        />
                      )}
                      <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground font-normal">
                        Auto-refill uses your preferred payment method to
                        replenish a spending profile when balance is below
                        $50.00. Turn off anytime.
                      </p>
                      <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-2 self-stretch">
                        <span className=" text-muted-foreground text-align-left font-medium text-sm">
                          Subtotal
                        </span>
                        <span className=" text-lg font-semibold text-foreground">
                          {`$${total?.toFixed(2) || "0.00"} `}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Card>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-2 mb-24 px-8">
        <Button
          variant="default"
          disabled={!total}
          className="w-full"
          onClick={async () => {
            // if (spendingProfiles && spendingProfiles.length > 0) {
            //   const profile = spendingProfiles[0];
            //   await addBalance(profile.id, parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)),"Dev mode add balance",
            //   "GENERIC REFERENCE ID",
            //   user.userId,
            //   "CREDIT_CARD");
            // }
            router.push(`/main/money/wallet/${account.id}/addMoney/checkout?amount=${total}`);
          }}          
        >
          Continue to Payment
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          className="w-full"
          onClick={() => router.push("/main/money")}
        >
          Skip for now
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
\main\money\wallet\[accountId]\addMoney\checkout\page.tsx
"use client";
import PageTitles from "@/components/PageTitles";
import { Card } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { supabaseBrowser } from "@/lib/supabase";
import HeaderBar from "@/components/HeaderBar";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import PaymentOptions from "@/components/PaymentOptionSelect";
import PaymentOptionForm from "@/components/PaymentOptionForm";
export default function CheckOut({ amount }: { amount: { total: number } }) {
  const [customRefillActive, setCustomRefillActive] = useState(false);
  const [customActive, setCustomActive] = useState(false);
  const [customRefillAmount, setCustomRefillAmount] = useState<string>("");
  const [customAmount, setCustomAmount] = useState<string>("");
  const [purchaseAmount, setPurchaseAmount] = useState<string>("");
  const [refillAmount, setRefillAmount] = useState<string>("");
  const [autoRefill, setAutoRefill] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState<number>(0);

  const [selectedPaymentType, setSelectedPaymentType] = useState<
    "ach" | "card" | "applePay"
  >("card");
  // const [autoRefill, setAutoRefill] = useState<{ student: string, autoRefill: boolean }[]>();
  const router = useRouter();
  const getStudentInformation = () => {
    supabaseBrowser.from("accounts").select("id, first_name, last_name");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateTotal = () => {
      console.log(customAmount, customRefillAmount, "CUSTOM AND CUSTOM REFILL");
      console.log(purchaseAmount, refillAmount, "PURCHASE AND REFILL");
      let refill = 0;
      let purchase = 0;
      if (customActive) {
        if (customAmount !== "" && customAmount !== "$") {
          purchase = parseFloat(customAmount.split("$")[1]);
        }
      } else if (purchaseAmount !== "") {
        purchase = parseFloat(purchaseAmount);
      }
      if (customRefillActive) {
        if (customRefillAmount !== "" && customRefillAmount !== "$") {
          refill = parseFloat(customRefillAmount.split("$")[1]);
        }
      } else if (refillAmount !== "") {
        refill = parseFloat(refillAmount);
      }
      setTotal(refill + purchase);
    };

    calculateTotal();
  }, [
    customAmount,
    customRefillAmount,
    customRefillActive,
    customActive,
    purchaseAmount,
    refillAmount,
  ]);
  const studentName = "Missy Elliot";
  const paymentAmount = 100.54;
  const demoTotal = 250.0;
  const softwareFee = 2.75;
  // const paymentString = "One-time payment"
  const paymentString = "Auto-refill $100 when balance drops below $50";
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col relative py-2 justify-between min-h-screen items-center gap-5 self-stretch">
      <HeaderBar leftButtonLabel={"Back"} leftButtonAction={"goBack"} />
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center self-stretch mx-8 mt-8">
        <PageTitles
          title="Checkout"
          subtitle={`
            Complete your payment
            `}
        />
        <div className="flex p-0 flex-col items-center gap-8 self-stretch">
          <Card className="flex p-3 flex-col items-center gap-0 self-stretch rounded-lg border bg-muted50">
            {/* {students.map((student, index) => { */}
            <div className="flex p-0 flex-col jt items-center gap-0 self-stretch">
              <span className="self-start text-sm font-bold">
                {`${studentName || "Missy Elliot"}`}
                <span className="font-sm font-normal">{` + $${paymentAmount.toFixed(
                  2
                )}`}</span>
              </span>
              <span className="self-start text-muted-foreground  text-sm font-normal ">{`${paymentString}`}</span>
            </div>
            <Separator className="flex my-3 px-0 flex-col justify-center items-center gap-10 self-stretch" />
            <div className="flex p-0 flex-col jt items-center gap-0 self-stretch">
              <span className="self-start text-sm font-bold">
                {`${studentName || "Missy Elliot"}`}
                <span className="font-sm font-normal">{` + $${paymentAmount.toFixed(
                  2
                )}`}</span>
              </span>
              <span className="self-start text-muted-foreground  text-sm font-normal ">{`${paymentString}`}</span>
            </div>
            <Separator className="flex my-3 px-0 flex-col justify-center items-center gap-10 self-stretch" />
            <span className=" self-stretch font-normal text-sm text-foreground">{`Pay today`}</span>
            <span className="self-stretch text-lg font-semibold">
              {`$${total.toFixed(2)}`}
              <span className=" text-muted-foreground text-sm font-normal">{` + $${softwareFee.toFixed(
                2
              )} software fee`}</span>
            </span>
          </Card>
          <div className="flex p-0 flex-col items-start gap-6 self-stretch mb-24">
            <PaymentOptions
              onClick={setSelectedPaymentType}
              selectedType={selectedPaymentType}
            />
            <PaymentOptionForm type={selectedPaymentType} refill={"100.00"} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

nextjs13 params use and i'm expecting that i will be able to render the value add money from `main\money\wallet\[accountId]\addMoney\page.tsx` to `\main\money\wallet\[accountId]\addMoney\checkout\page.tsx`